# Spring attribute not being added to model

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, model, controller

I want to add some attributes to the model, but for some reason, one of the attributes isn't being added to the model for a specific request handler.

The two attributes are `numberDeleted` and `usersDeleted`.

`usersDeleted` for some reason is not added to the model on the third request handler.

Here is the code: (Note: Some lines of code has been removed for brevity. Only the relevant code is displayed).

First I delete some selected users:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String delete(
            @ModelAttribute("credentials") Credentials credentials,
            @ModelAttribute("deleteUsersForm") DeleteUsersForm form,
            @ModelAttribute("searchCriteria") SearchForm searchForm,
            Model model, RedirectAttributes redirect) {

        String[] usersDeleted = form.getCheckedUsers();
        if (usersDeleted != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < usersDeleted.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("user (delete): " + usersDeleted[i]);
            }
        }

        redirect.addFlashAttribute("usersDeleted", usersDeleted);
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("numberDeleted", numberDeleted);
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("searchForm", searchForm);

        return "redirect:" + searchForm.getSelectedOption();
    }
```

After the chosen users are deleted from the database, I make a REST API call to get the currently existing users and add them to the model, as well as the `numberDeleted` and `usersDeleted` from the delete function above:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllUsers(@ModelAttribute Credentials credentials,
            RedirectAttributes redirect, Model model) {

        SearchForm searchForm = new SearchForm("/getAllUsers", "allUsers");

        redirect.addFlashAttribute("users", users);
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("searchCriteria", searchForm);

        /* If users deleted: */
        Integer numberDeleted = (Integer) model.asMap().get("numberDeleted");
        String[] usersDeleted = (String[]) model.asMap().get("usersDeleted");
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("numberDeleted", numberDeleted);
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("usersDeleted,", usersDeleted);

        if (usersDeleted != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < usersDeleted.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("user: (getAllUsers) " + usersDeleted[i]);
            }
        }

        return "redirect:/adminHome";
    }
```

The `usersDeleted` and `numberDeleted` are not null up to this point and I can print out their value.

Then I call the request to list the users:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/adminHome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAdminHomePage(Model model) {


        SearchForm searchCriteria = (SearchForm) model.asMap().get(
                "searchCriteria");

        /* If users were deleted: */
        Integer numberDeleted = (Integer) model.asMap().get("numberDeleted");
        String[] usersDeleted = (String[]) model.asMap().get("usersDeleted");
        model.addAttribute("numberDeleted", numberDeleted);
        model.addAttribute("usersDeleted,", usersDeleted);

        if (usersDeleted != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < usersDeleted.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("user: (adminhome) " + usersDeleted[i]);
            }
        }
         .....
        return "admin_home";
    }
```

However, at this point, `usersDeleted` is null (since nothing prints out) but `numberDeleted` is not null.

I literally do not understand what is going on. How come it is null? I explicitly added it to the model.

**EDIT 1:**
Currently, my only workaround is to add `usersDeleted` to `@SessionAttributes`.

But I should not have to resort to this.

Comment: There is a type. Remove the comma:  model.addAttribute("usersDeleted,", usersDeleted); shoudl be  model.addAttribute("usersDeleted", usersDeleted);

Comment: @Rossi Robinsion WOW thank you! Maybe I need to take a nap or take a break. My mind is clobbered lol. Can you write that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: That's happens. No worries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Kingamere comments, I am posting this. There was a typo on the model key.

```
model.addAttribute("usersDeleted,", usersDeleted);
```

There was an extra comma at the end of the usersDeleted. After you remove that comma, it works perfectly for Kingmere.

```
model.addAttribute("usersDeleted", usersDeleted);
```